# Thread exiting with uncaught exception

Tags: java, android, debugging, exception

my app is nearly done. I'm only doing the bugfixing now. I'm running into a problem that I sometimes randomly (so not always the same time or after the same actions are done) get my app crashed. LogCat just tells me

```
threadid=11 thread eixiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4134d2a0)
```

But there is no "caused by" what normally would come so I can actually catch the exception. When it crashes (randomly) this gets written into my console

```
[2013-10-22 15:39:36 - ddms] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.read(Client.java:698)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:311)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

[2013-10-22 15:39:36 - ddms] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.read(Client.java:698)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:311)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

But these aren't classes of mine. How can I catch the exception? Please be aware that I'm not able to post the whole code here. It's firstly too much and I'm not allowed to... The app crashes randomly. I don't know why and how to handle it. Any suggestions?

I'm running the app on a galaxy note right now.

Comment: in any place of your code base, are you using `reentrantLock.lock()`?

Comment: You could look into grepCode ... what Android build is the traces from?

Comment: No I'm not using reentrantLock.lock(). Fildor what exactly is grepCode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These errors occur when something is wrong with the communication between DDMS and the device. They're generally harmless, but you can solve them by restarting the ADB server:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

If you're using the emulator and this doesn't solve the problem, try deleting and recreating the AVD.

Comment: So, when I will finally deploy the app it won't have any effects for the user? Since its just an emulator problem?

Comment: @Musterknabe Most likely, but you should test it first by using a real device or by recreating the AVD.

Comment: That's the shocking part. I'm currently using a real device

Comment: @Musterknabe Try: adb kill-server, adb start-server in the terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Is there no "Caused by..." text in your logcat? It should point to the code that has caused the error.

Comment: No, there isn't that's what's shocking me. Just the entry in the console